# dynamically displaying prices of in app purchases in multiple currencies

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to display prices for in-app purchases in multiple currencies.
The user can choose 1 item, 2 items or 3 items at a time. The price updates it self at runtime(the user selects one item, than selects 2 for example), so that the user can see it being updated. This is fairly easy to accomplish if the price is displayed only in US dollars. When adding euros or British £ things start to get messy. How does one dynamically display IAP prices in multiple currencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you. The following code prints the localised title, currency code and the price.

```
    let product = ... //your SKProduct
    if let currencyCode = product.priceLocale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode) as? String {
        print(product.localizedTitle + " : " + currencyCode + " \(product.price)")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. I tried that but I am getting an error. I edited my question with it.

Comment: Try `objectForKey:` instead of `valueForKey:`

Comment: okay that worked. The debugger throws "myLocalizedTitle : EUR 0.99" which is nice. Is it possible to change  "EUR" string to character  €?

Comment: Replace `NSLocaleCurrencyCode` with `NSLocaleCurrencySymbol`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the function I use. Seems like some properties of `SKProduct` are not filled, when you're in a non-supported store somewhere in the world.

```
internal func getPrice(#priceLocale: NSLocale!, price: NSDecimalNumber, count: Int) -> String? {
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.formatterBehavior = NSNumberFormatterBehavior.Behavior10_4
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = priceLocale
    return formatter.stringFromNumber(price * count)
}
```

This is the function I use (Actually as a property in `extension SKProduct`)
It returns `nil`, if something goes wrong with formatting `count` or `price`.